# How can I compare user input to string stored into file?

Tags: c, function, file, file-handling

I gotta write a file-handing code which will compare the string received from the user to a string of char stored into a file in C. I've trying since yesterday. I have no clue on how to do that. I tried many things, but nothing seems to work.

```
//
//  2.c
//  IFTM Exercises
//
//  Created by Lelre Ferreira on 10/27/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Lelre Ferreira. All rights reserved.
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]){

    FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "w");
    char text[] = "hi hi hi hi hi hi"; //string to be allocated into the file
    char c, userInput[] = "hi"; // simulates the user input
    int i = 0, count = 0;



    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Failure to create file.\n");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++) {
            printf("Inserting: [%c]\n", text[i]);
            fputc(text[i], file);
        }
        printf("All done.\n");
    }
    fclose(file);


    fopen("file.txt", "r");
    while ((c = fgetc(file) != EOF)){
        fscanf(file,   "%s",   text);
        if (strcmp(userInput, text) == 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);



    printf("Many times present: %d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is... the space between every word of the string in the file, because I have to check if there's another word starting, for instance... (Hi Hi)... I thought about using something like this in my code but I did not work as well.

```
while ((c = fgetc(file) != EOF)){ // While the end of the file does not happen keep running.
    if ((c = fgetc(file) != ' ')) { //If an blank space is found... I does not make any sense actually. I'm desesperated.
        strcmp(userInput, text){
            count++
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, `c` should be `int`. Just saying. Related to your question I see no reason for that `fgetc` logic in your reader loop for the search. `while (fscanf(file, "%s", text) == 1)` would seem more appropriate, losing the `fscanf` call in the loop itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((c = fgetc(file) != EOF)){ 
    if ((c = fgetc(file) != ' ')) { 
        strcmp(userInput, text){
            count++
        }
    }
}
```

There are three major problems here.

First, `c = fgetc(file) != EOF` is the same as `c = (fgetc(file) != EOF)` which obviously is not what you want. It should be `(c = fgetc(file)) != EOF`

Second, the above statement has (provided you did not get an EOF) actually read a character. So the if statement should be `if(c != ' ')`

Third, `c` needs to be declared as an `int`

Comment: Thank you guys! I will try to correct my code once I get home but... Why does C should be declared as int instead of char? It's intention is to receive character from the file, I thought it should be declared as char... I didn't get how it works... I'd appreciate an explanation about it. Thanks in advance.